# How to use "group by" before "join" on mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have the following query which contains duplicate user_id's. I don't want to see a user more than one. I decided to use group by as in the following:

```
SELECT u.`ID`, u.`user_login`, u.`user_registered`, u.`display_name` 
FROM purchase_key p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id  
WHERE  (  `product_id` = 1 OR  `product_id` = 2 )  
AND  `create_date` <= '2015-09-20'   AND  `create_date` >= '2014-09-01'  
group by p.user_id order by p.`create_date` asc
```

But is there a way to do that grouping before join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.`ID`, u.`user_login`, u.`user_registered`, u.`display_name` 
FROM (SELECT * FROM purchase_key GROUP BY user_id ) p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id  
WHERE  (  `product_id` = 1 OR  `product_id` = 2 )  
AND  `create_date` <= '2015-09-20'   AND  `create_date` >= '2014-09-01'  
 order by p.`create_date` asc
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While strictly speaking this will do what was requested, the create_date for the purchase_key that the result is ordered by could be from any purchase by the user (hence the order is pretty meaningless), but worse it is likely to exclude purchase records with a create date within the required range in favour of ones outside the range, hence missing records.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to do this.  Unlikely that it will help with performance unless the indexes are very poor.

Not sure the LEFT OUTER JOIN is useful, as the only fields your query returns are ones from the left joined table. Hence if no user were found for some purchases you would just have a load of null rows returned.

But doing the sub query to get the list of users, with the max create date for that user within the required date range (while not strictly necessary for MySQL most flavours of SQL would give an error if you return fields that are not in the group by clause and not aggregate fields), and using an INNER JOIN gives you the following:-

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_login, u.user_registered, u.display_name 
FROM 
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(create_date) AS max_create_date
    FROM purchase_key 
    WHERE  product_id IN (1, 2)  
    AND  create_date BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2015-09-20'
    GROUP BY user_id 
) p 
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id  
ORDER BY p.max_create_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see user more than once, try to use `DISTINCT` in your first line.